# Cannot telnet into my FTP enabled AWS Windows 2012 R2 server

Tags: ftp, windows-server-2012-r2

I've created a new AWS server (Windows 2012 R2) and I'm not able to login into the server using telnet, as shown below.  I've included screen shots as shown below to assist.  I'm not sure what else I've missed?  I've tried it locally and that works using the ftpuser I've defined.

Any help greatly appreciated.

Thanks,

**FTP firewall settings**

[image]

**Ping works**

[image]

I get the following error when trying to connect from other machine

**Error message**

[image]

**AWS security group settings**

[image]

**IIS settings**

[image]

**Update #1 - added TCP port 23 rule in AWS**

[image]

**Update #2 - checked FTP server is installed**

[image]

**Update #3 - Have installed telnet server**

[image]

Comment: Sorry, not trying to get off topic. But, you are using telnet on the internal network only, not over the Internet, is that correct? Also you are aware that it is an insecure protocol (that includes ftp as well). From a security standpoint, it is not a good option to use. Anyone with a sniffer can see all the data flowing in plain text.

Comment: I can think of NO valid reason to enable a Telnet server on an EC2 instance under any circumstances. You really need to take a step back and explain what you are trying to accomplish by enabling Telnet. No matter what you are trying to do, there's a correct way to do it.

Answer (score 3):

The line you highlight in your AWS security group is for ICMP. You will need to add an entry into your security group for the telnet port TCP/23.

You'll also need to have something listening (a telnet server) on your host.

Comment: Thanks for helping, I've added a custom TCP rule on port 23, as shown in my updated question but I still can't connect to it.

Comment: @JamesRadford Do you have a telnet service running?

Comment: believe so, please see my updated screen shot

Comment: is it a firewall problem as I can remote desktop onto the server and ftp with localhost?

Comment: I don't see anything that suggests a telnet server is running.

Comment: let me google how to check

Comment: looking at services.msc I cannot see anything called Telnet*, only Microsoft FTP service is running

Comment: almost there now, I've logged in (had to install telnet server and enable it in services.msc) then from another computer I managed to login but got logged out straight away due to telnetclient groups issue

Comment: Telnet isn't FTP. Port 23 isn't FTP.

Answer (score 0):

thanks to all the comments, after all the great help to get telnet up and working you need to check/ setup the following:

- enable tcp port 23 on AWS
- check on the AWS server the Telnet server is running (you might need to enable it services.msc)
- create a ftp website in IIS and create/ assign a user for telneting.